# Big-O time required to iterate through a for loop within a while loop of the same list

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having trouble determining the Big-O running time for the following type of code:

```
typedef map<string, vector<string> >::iterator MapIter;

while(!myMap.empty()) {

    for(MapIter it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++) {

       // if it->first is the key for the pairing I want to remove
       //    then erase it

       break;

    }

}
```

The code here really isn't super important, my complete code works fine, I'm just trying to determine the Big-O analysis.  What particularly confuses me is that I'm iterating through the map `n` times, then `n-1` times, and so on until the map is empty.  Would this take `O(n!)` time?

Comment: Not related to your big-O question, but why are you doing this?  If your for loop is seeking a match on `it->first` as claimed by the comment, then you can use the `map::find` function instead and reduce to time to O(nlog2n)....

Comment: I agree that my algorithm was rather poor.  At the time, it didn't occur to me that `map::find` was `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Sure - no worries.  For clarification - each `map::find` is O(log2N) where N is the current container `size()`, but calling it for every element ends up a smidge better than O(Nlog2N) (because N is reducing as it goes).  Calling it O(Nlog2N) is sanest though, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 + 0 = n(n+1)/2
```

which is roughly

```
   O(n^2)
```